# Как сделать поиск по реляцонным таблицам(моделям) в yii?

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Есть таблица tbl_test(тесты):

1. id,
2. title
3. law_id(FK)

и есть таблица tbl_law(законы):

1. id
2. title

Соответственно модели Test и Law. Тест принадлежит закону (BELONGS_TO). В модели Test прописано след. отношение:

```
'law' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Law', 'law_id')
```

В TestController есть метод admin():

```
public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Test('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Test']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Test'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

В представлении admin.php след. код:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'test-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'title',
        array(
            'name'=>'law.title',
            'filter'=>'<input type="text" maxlength="500" name="Test[law.title]">',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

В форме поиска в админке выводятся названия id, название теста и название закона. Но по названию закона данные не сортируются. **Вопрос: как решить эту проблему?**

И ответьте пожалуйста что означает инициализация объекта с передачей в конструктор 'search'? То есть, например, `$model=new Test('search');`. Если это как-то связано с методом `search()` модели `Test`, то вот его код:

```
public function search()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
        $criteria->compare('law_id',$this->law_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

В yii еще совсем зеленый поэтому не судите строго пожалуйста. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4534-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/)  смотрели  а вот [так](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/4002)  пробывали, ну а если у вас совсем много времени поробуйте за бэкапиться  и использовать [данное](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/index.html) расширение. У него есть свой crud генератор через него создайте также контроллер и виды (хотя не обещаю что будет все лучше).

И ответьте пожалуйста что означает инициализация объекта с передачей в конструктор 'search'? То есть, например, $model=new Test('search'); --> Не знаю, может он сразу к функции обращается.

Comment: Бесполезен ваша ответ к сожалению.

Comment: $model=$model - уже удалил это бред. Опечаточка вышла